# Duplicated keycodes for F10-12 and mute/increase/decrease volume

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I bought Arteck HW086 keyboard. I'm using it with Ubuntu 16.04.

*In advance: I tried a lot of googling and trying to solve this using 'similar' topics. All of them are slightly different, found none applicable to the case.*

[problem pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiXmC.jpg)

The problems:

**F10** has the same keycode as **Fn** + **F6** (mutes audio)

**F11** has the same keycode as **Fn** + **F5** (decreases volume)

**F12** has the same keycode as **Fn** + **F6** (increases volume)

Output from `xev` after pressing **F10**:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x212, subw 0x0, time 92088, (597,541), root:(597,593),
    state 0x10, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x212, subw 0x0, time 92160, (597,541), root:(597,593),
    state 0x10, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Output from `xev` after pressing **F11** (no `KeyPress` somehow):

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x212, subw 0x0, time 177888, (86,417), root:(684,736),
    state 0x10, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Output from `xev` after pressing **F12** (no `KeyPress` again):

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x212, subw 0x0, time 277990, (545,612), root:(545,664),
    state 0x10, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I would like to have simple **F10**, **F11** and **F12** on the keys. Especially because volume manipulation is already under **Fn** + **F**s

I can't even remap it, because I would have to remap for example volume up to **F12** which would make **Fn** way of increasing volume stop work.

Is there anything I can do?

PS -> my build in laptop keyboard is working OK.

Edit:
I tested it on two another laptops, first with 16.04 second with 17.something. Same issue (so it is not my system specific).

Edit 2:
On OSX it works correctly.